# Choosing a MapReduce Design Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, hadoop, mapreduce

For my honours project, I'm researching ways of processing the very large quantities of data produced by a mass spectrometer (MS) within the University's Life Sciences department.

I've been reading MapReduce Design Patterns & Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, and I'm trying to connect the data I have to a particular map & reduce pattern.

The first step is to find the ***weighted peak*** for each curve. Performing a calculation to reduce the 6 or 7 points (rows) to a single point with info like max/min, average.

- The data is in ~8GB CSV files that look like this:

  ```
  100312_EXP229_GFPIP_5,1,0.00056783449000000002,0,402.0745297608135,1135.039794921875,1,0,0,0,0,0
  ```
- Each row is essentially a single point on a graph, with X & Y coords.
- The points are grouped into curves by one of the columns. So I know
  for each record, which curve it belongs to.
- The number of points in each curve varies, it's usually around 4 - 8 points.

My problem is most of the example seem to deal with problems line by line, e.g. Word Count. I need to process N rows at a time, although I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about solving this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case it should be sufficient to process the file line by line and for each line output `<curve, point>` in your mapper. The reducer will receive all points, which belong to a single curve: `<curve, {point1, point2, ... }>` as input. Thus you can calculate the max/min/avg based on the points of a curve in the reducer and output `<curve, max/min/avg>` as the final result.

PS. For processing exactly `N` rows of the input file in each mapper you could use the [NLineInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/NLineInputFormat.html).

Comment: Yeah I thought trying to pass the mapper multiple rows wasn't the right thing to do. Thanks for the `N` rows tip though! I'm now using the mapper to bundle single point data into a custom `Writable` class, then performing the calculations in the reducer as you suggest and it works very well, thanks for your help.